# Npm project inside another npm project

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

I want to organize my project to easily reuse some modules. I am not sure that my approach is correct.

Let's say we have a main project with two sub-projects. Something like this:

```
- main-project
  - index.js
  - project.json
  - node_modules
    - reused_module
      ...
  - sub-project1
    - index.js
    - project.json
    - node_modules
      - private_module1
        ...
  - sub-project2
    - index.js
    - project.json
    - node_modules
      - private_module2
        ...
```

Now both project2 inner1 and inner2 have access to reused_module, but I'm wondering about the dependencies in their project.json files.

If reused_module is listed in the dependency section of inner1/package.json, it will be copied to its own node_modules (which I would like to avoid, to force the reuse).

If reused_module is NOT listed in inner1/package.json, this dependency will be kind of "hidden".

Is there something I should now about this?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does `main-project` depend on both sub-projects?

Comment: You might find `npm link` useful: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: @RyanZim: main-project is actually kind of a project "placeholder" for other projects, created basically to tackle this reuse. I would put some gulp tasks and other development things there, no real code.
If there is some better way to cover this reuse scenario I would be happy to know it. Actually that's my question all about

Comment: @cartant: thank you, I will

Comment: If you're just trying to save disk space, you can simply change npm's `link` option: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#link. (This is distinct from the cli command `npm link`)

Comment: If I understood both suggestions well, they both involve globally installed npm modules. Note that in my case, I deal only with local modules (main-project is kind of top-level folder, but not global level).

Comment: @Aleks what you need is three folders on your SSD, flat, at the same level. Then `npm link` both `sub-project1` and `sub-project2` to be available in your system. Then `npm link sub-project1` and `npm link sub-project2` while your are in root of `main-project`. Then you will be able to develop `project1` and `project2` and instantly consume them on `main-project`. That's how I work on my libs.